# is there anyway to zoom into visual studio 2010 if you dont have a scroll on your mouse

Tags: visual-studio-2010

is there any shortcut key to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>.</kbd> to zoom in and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> to zoom out.

You can get download the shortcut posters [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=92CED922-D505-457A-8C9C-84036160639F&displaylang=en)

Comment: Also in cpp, f# , text files, etc apparently

Comment: This answer may work if you have the default keyboard mappings. However, some users prefer to change the keyboard mappings. In some cases addins or extensions overload keyboard mappings as well. For example in my configuration the zoom-in shortcut works as suggested in your answer but the zoom-out shotcut opens a window of one of the addins.

Comment: Not may, WILL work with the default keyboard mappings. And of course I have to answer with the defaults, I cannot say: "in My Visual Studio I zoom In with VolumeUp and Zoom out with the Power Button"

Answer (score 5):

In my install, I find that I have to head in through Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard and map "View.ZoomIn" and "View.ZoomOut" to get this working. This could be because ReSharper has modified my keyboard shortcuts, however.

Comment: I can confirm that: it's due to ReSharper.